# Proving that $\beta^{-1}\circ \alpha $ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, curves, submanifold

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $\alpha:[a,b]\to \mathbb R^n$ and $\beta:[c,d]\to \mathbb R^n$ be two regular, injective curves with the same trace in $\mathbb R^n$.
>
> Prove that $\beta^{-1}\circ\alpha:[a,b] \to [c,d]$ is differentiable and it's derivative is never zero.

I tried to prove that, for any $k\in [a,b]$, the limit: $$\lim_{t\to k} \frac{\beta^{-1}(\alpha(k)) - \beta^{-1}(\alpha(t))}{k-t}$$

exists. I wasn't able to conclude anything because we don't know if $\beta^{-1}$ is continuous or differentiable.

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you derive that $\beta^{-1}$ is continuous? Consider the domain and codomain of $\beta$.

Comment: I tried. It it using the inverse function theorem? @legionwhale

Comment: Perhaps; it is possible that we are using different names for the same theorem. The theorem I am thinking of uses that $[c,d]$ is compact and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Hausdorff. It only proves the continuity of $\beta^{-1}$ though.

Comment: omg, how did I forget that!? I started taking differential geometry and all of a sudden forgot that topology exists smh Thank you. Do you have any idea if it's possible to prove that $\beta^{-1}$ is differentiable? @legionwhale

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not studied differential geometry so I don't know :-) but I thought I could at least help with the question of continuity.

Comment: $\beta$ is differentiable from the get-go, and since it is regular, the inverse function theorem tells us that $\beta^{-1}$ is differentiable. Since the composition of differentiable maps is differentiable, the composition $\beta^{-1} \circ \alpha$ is differentiable.

Comment: inverse function theorem is indeed helpful. Fix a point $s_0\in [c,d]$ and define $B(s,\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_{n-1})=\beta(s)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sigma_i\xi_i$, where $\{\xi_1,\dots, \xi_{n-1}\}$ is a set of vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $\{\beta'(s_0),\xi_1\dots, \xi_{n-1}\}$ is a basis. You see that $B$ maps $[c,d]\times\{0_{\Bbb{R}^{n-1}}\}$ onto the image of $\beta$. Apply the IFT to $B$ around $(s_0,0,\dots, 0)$; the local inverse of $B$ maps the curve back smoothly. I'll leave it to you to fill in the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $J  = \alpha([a,b]) = \beta([c,d]) \subset \mathbb R^n$ be the common trace of both curves. Then $\beta : [c,d] \to J$ is a continuous bijection from a compact to a Hausdorff space, thus a homeomorphism. Hence $\beta^{-1        } : J \to [a,b]$ is a homeomorphism. Similarly $\alpha :[a,b] \to J$ is a homeomorphism. This shows that
$$u = \beta^{-1} \circ \alpha : [a,b] \to [c,d]$$
also is a homeomorphism.

For $t \ne t_0$ we have
$$\frac{\alpha(t) - \alpha(t_0)}{t - t_0} = \frac{\beta(u(t)) - \beta(u(t_0))}{t - t_0} = \frac{\beta(u(t)) - \beta(u(t_0))}{u(t) - u(t_0)} \cdot \frac{u(t) - u(t_0)}{t - t_0} . \tag{1} $$
Note that $u(t) - u(t_0) \ne 0$ because $u$ is injective and $\beta(u(t)) - \beta(u(t_0)) = \alpha(t) - \alpha(t_0) \ne 0$ because $\alpha$ is injective. Taking the norm gives us
$$\left\lVert \frac{\alpha(t) - \alpha(t_0)}{t - t_0} \right\rVert = \left\lVert  \frac{\beta(u(t)) - \beta(u(t_0))}{u(t) - u(t_0)} \right\rVert \cdot \left\lvert  \frac{u(t) - u(t_0)}{t - t_0} \right\rvert. \tag{2} $$

Thus
$$\left\lvert \frac{u(t) - u(t_0)}{t - t_0} \right\rvert = \frac{\left\lVert \frac{\alpha(t) - \alpha(t_0)}{t - t_0}\right\rVert}{\left\lVert \frac{\beta(u(t)) - \beta(u(t_0))}{u(t) - u(t_0)} \right\rVert}. \tag{3} $$
Since $u(t) \to u(t_0)$ as $t \to t_0$, we conclude that
$$\lim_{t \to t_0} \left\lvert \frac{u(t) - u(t_0)}{t - t_0} \right\rvert = q := \frac{\left\lVert \alpha'(t_0)\right\rVert}{\left\lVert \beta'(u(t_0))\right\rVert} \ne 0 .\tag{4}$$

$u$ may be strictly increasing (in which case $u(a) = c$ and $u(b) = d$) or strictly decreasing (in which case $u(a) = d$ and $u(b) = c$).

In the strictly increasing case we have
$$\left\lvert \frac{u(t) - u(t_0)}{t - t_0} \right\rvert = \frac{u(t) - u(t_0)}{t - t_0} \tag{5}$$
which implies
$$\lim_{t \to t_0} \frac{u(t) - u(t_0)}{t - t_0} = q  \ne 0 .\tag{6}$$
In the strictly decreasing case we have
$$\left\lvert \frac{u(t) - u(t_0)}{t - t_0} \right\rvert = -\frac{u(t) - u(t_0)}{t - t_0} \tag{7}$$
which implies
$$\lim_{t \to t_0} \frac{u(t) - u(t_0)}{t - t_0} = -q  \ne 0 .\tag{8}$$